# Nested expression language is not working in mule

Tags: nested, expression, mule

I was trying to use nested expression in mule but its not working.

```
<When evaluator="json"     expression="status/#groovy:message.getSessionProperty('user')]='Active'">
```

but when i tried to use static way, it was working.

```
<When evaluator="json" expression="status/john='Active'">
```

and  i am using mule 3.3.0 version. It was mentioned that nested expression is working in mule 3.3.0

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to concatenate the expressions as opposed of nesting them.

For example you when condition would look like the following:

```
<when expression="#[json:status]/#[groovy:message.getSessionProperty('user')]='Active'">
```

Beware that ever since Mule 3.3.0 the default and recommanded expression language is [MEL](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Mule+Expression+Language)

Comment: I tried with above mentioned pattern still no luck. Looks like json just neglecting the expression language like groovy etc.,

I have also tried to log it 
`code`<logger level="INFO" message="#[string:#[json:status/#[groovy:message.getSessionProperty('user')]]]" />`code`

it just displays as #[json:status/#[groovy:message.getSessionProperty('user')]] but the expected to be displayed is is "Active"

Comment: The logger you are using is not following my recommendation: you are still nesting EL rather than concatenating them. Using <logger level="INFO" message="#[json:status]/#[groovy:message.getSessionProperty('user')]" /> should work (no need of using the string EL since both EL will return string)